# Losing decimal places Java Double

Tags: java

Using Java i am getting a weird result

```
Double width = super.getWidth()/(32);
System.out.println(super.getWidth() + "  " + width);
```

prints `312 9.0`

312/32 should be 9.75?

Comment: Does `super.getWidth()` return an `int`?

Comment: You're doing integer division. Try `super.getWidth() / 32.0;`

Comment: It sure is an integer

Comment: As @Jesper said then -- you are doing an integer division!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `super.getWidth()` returns an integral type (an `int`, a `long`, etc.) the precision is lost during the division. When you divide a value of an integral type by an `int`, only the integer portion of the result is kept, while the fractional part is discarded.

Divide by `32.0` to fix the problem:

```
double width = super.getWidth()/32.0;
System.out.println(super.getWidth() + "  " + width);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
Double width = super.getWidth()/(32.0);
```

When the java compiler comes across your original code, it sees two integers, and returns an integer. This way, it sees an integer and a double, therefore returning a double.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Double width = super.getWidth()/(32.0);
System.out.println(super.getWidth() + "  " + width);
```

Comment: You should "try" answering the question, not just providing a fixed code snippet without explaining or even highlighting the change ;)